# Fixed Header Issue - addClass doesn't work on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a hidden header which has to appear once I scroll web page below 100px. The header contains logo which has to be hidden as well. The issue is that on the page load everything is hidden same as it has to be, however on scroll only the head appears, the logo is still missing. But if I refresh the page when it is below 100px from top the logo appears and works fine even if I go back on top.

Could you please explain what might be a reason behind the issue as I could not find any proper solution.

HTML

```
<header>
    <a id="logo" href="index.html"></a>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header{
    position: fixed;
    top: -50px;
    left: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);
    z-index:9999;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
header.show{
    top:0;
}

a#logo{
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top: inherit;
    left: -80px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url('images/logos/logo.svg');
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($('body').scrollTop() > 100){
            $("header").addClass('show');
        }
        else{
            $("header").removeClass('show')
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Do you really need set absolute on the logo? or change to left:0;top:0; and see.

Comment: I've created a jsfiddle with your code and the problem not happens with all browsers, but changing the top of a#logo resolved: http://jsfiddle.net/a1znyb6m

Comment: I need left to be -80px but changing the top to 0 solved the issue. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the given answers are correct :)

The problem is the `inherit` value of `a#logo` `top`

```
a#logo{
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0; /*make it 0, and it will work*/
    left: -80px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url('images/logos/logo.svg');
}
```

Comment: `0` or can set it to `initial`. Both will work. And yes, this is the right answer!

Answer (score 4):

You now only have logic in your scroll-event handler. To add logic in your scroll-event and page on load replace your logic into a function like:

```
var checkScroll = function() {
    if($('body').scrollTop() > 100){
        $("header").addClass('show');
    }
    else{
        $("header").removeClass('show')
    }
}
```

Now change your javascript to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkScroll();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        checkScroll();
    });
});
```

Comment: This won't change anything, the `addClass` function is still within the scroll function, so nothing will happen on page load.

Comment: With the CSS provided this will not make any difference. not the right answer.

Comment: I didn't try it as the solution with changing inherit to 0 for the logo element fixed the issue. But thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `top: inherit;` from `a#logo` and use t his JS

```
function showHeader() {
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > 100) 
        $("header").css('top', '0px');
    else 
        $("header").css('top', '-50px')
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    showHeader();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        showHeader();
    });
});
```